# What is wrong with this simple concatenation

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm just trying to concatenate a few lines of text in a text file using Node.js.
The results and expected results are shown below and aren't the same. I'm not sure why I'm getting the results I'm getting, it looks like it's overwriting the previous line.

> Goal: Concatenate Line and the following Sub items on the same line

**app.js**

```
   'use strict'
    const fs = require('fs')

    let targetRegex = /Line.*/;
    let concatStatement = '';

    fs.readFileSync('input.txt').toString().split('\n')
        .forEach(function (line) {

            if (targetRegex.test(line)) {
                concatStatement = line;
            }
            else {
                concatStatement += line
                console.log(concatStatement);

            }
        });
```

**input.txt**

```
Line11
SubA
Line22
SubB
```

**results**

```
SubA11
SubB22
```

**expected**

```
Line11SubA
Line22Subb
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this program on ubuntu and it produced output that you are expecting.

The problem for you could be line variable that is getting returned in each iteration of forEach is having carriage return at the beginning because of which it is overriding characters.

I verified this by intentionally adding carriage return at the beginning of line variable and it started producing the output that you are getting.

```
'use strict'
 const fs = require('fs')

 let targetRegex = /Line*/;
 let concatStatement = '';

 fs.readFileSync('input.txt').toString().split('\n')
.forEach(function (line) {
    line = '\r' + line

    if (targetRegex.test(line)) {
        concatStatement = line;
    }
    else {
        concatStatement += line
        console.log(concatStatement);

    }
});
```

This produces

**SubA11**
**SubB22**

And if I comment this line

```
line = '\r' + line
```

then it produces(on my platform) the output you are expecting.

**Solution**

To solve the problem can you check the line separator for the input.txt file and use correct separator as text split.